# Why am I getting a SQL Syntax Error in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

Hi I'm trying to insert some data into a MySQL database. However I keep getting a syntax error from the MySQL.connector. I'm not sure what is causing this I've tried all the examples on the mysql website but none of them work. I could get this to work on my old web server for a different website but now its not working.

My code is (the ID is a 30 string of upper-case letters and numbers and the UserID is a 20 digit string):

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO LoginSessions(SessionID,UserID) VALUES({0},{1})'''.format(ID,UserID)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
<class 'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError'>: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ORPFDQE0CKYVY1LN0RPW',))' at line 1
```

Thanks for any help in advance. It will be greatly appreciated it's been bugging me for a few hours. I've tried everything I possibly know and am about to give up!

Comment: _"I've tried everything I possibly know_". Please add "print and examine the resulting SQL string" to your toolbelt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use format to create a sql-command, use placeholders, then you don't have to take care, that the types of your IDs is correctly encoded:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO LoginSessions(SessionID,UserID) VALUES(%s,%s)'''
cursor.execute(sql, (ID,UserID))
```

Comment: ive tried that and i get this error

    <class 'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError'>: Failed processing format-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

Comment: What are the types of `ID` and `UserID`, really?

Comment: they should be strings but im not sure what they are any more do you know how to find that out

Comment: Hi figured it out for some reason the UserID was a tuple